# Want to make all text black in VS Cose

Tags: text, visual-studio-code, colors

I am using VS Code and have very weak eyes and would like to make all the text of color block as it will make text much more readable. How can i go about it?

Comment: Look through the settings, you can edit every color in there

Comment: you can look for *High Contrast" color themes. There is one default installed.

Comment: i tried searching in the settings but wasn't able to find it. I also tried editing settings.json file but was unable to find the property on the vs code customization page  which would complete the task.

Comment: high contrast themes makes comments in the editor very light in color.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme